# Image with color in React Native TabbarIOS.item

Tags: ios, reactjs, uiimage, react-native, uitabbaritem

I've been trying to accomplish a tabbed app similar to the image using `TabbarIOS` and `TabbarIOS.item` in RN.

[image]

I've accomplished adding the image but the color is changed to the default grey and only changes to blue when selected.

Is there a way to accomplish this using `TabbarIOS.item`?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the unselectedTintColor property work? - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tabbarios.html#unselectedtintcolor

Comment: You are correct! Updated to 0.28 and everything works. Thanks! Please write this as an answer so I can accept it @Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [unselectedTintColor](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tabbarios.html#unselectedtintcolor) property should help.